# Having problems converting formulas to arrays

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the sample workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqkXO8sdpeP9GPerdg8o2zcSiTV7o8gA-07iBvqw4Yw/edit#gid=1252102463

I'm working off the size tab but I have a "workingsize" tab that someone helped me with. The formulas in that sheet are working great.

ColN in Size corresponds to ColR in WorkingSize. In the absence of context, I'm looking for those two outputs to be identical and can't figure out how to get the formulas to behave correctly.

For more context on Size:

- Eventually, the data entered into the red section will exist on an entirely different sheet. I'm good at referencing between sheets but just wanted everyone to be aware. This is the data I'm having trouble with.
- in K6 & below, you enter in a type of pizza. right now it's free text but ultimately, it will be a drop down from the range A2:A. That range also matches the headers in F3:H3. In theory, as new items are added to the A2 range, new columns will appear here.
- ColL is a number - it represents a dough ball weight.
- ColM is identifying which column from the table to be searching against.
- ColN then takes the weight, rounds it to the nearest value in the corresponding col for type, and then outputs the corresponding size.

ColN in Size is my attempt to take the formulas from colR in workingsize and turn them into an array.

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are two totally different products, with vast differences between them. If you're using Google Sheets, the Excel-related tags are inappropriate. Please use only tags that are actually relevant to your post. Tag-spamming is highly discouraged, and is a very good way to get your post quickly downvoted and closed. I've removed the Excel tags from your post.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks - good to know for future reference. certainly loath spam!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with XLOOKUP. With INDEX and XMATCH you narrow the weightes by the match on the name of the column. Then with MAP you can convert it in an array. Change the last -1 to 1 if you want to round it up instead of down:

```
=MAP(K6:K,L6:L,LAMBDA(type,wt,IF(wt="","",XLOOKUP(wt,INDEX(E4:H,,XMATCH(type,E3:H3)),D4:D,,-1))))
```

[image]

PS: I deleted the column of key value, since it was not necessary

---

UPDATE:

To find closest value, you can use this: it sorts D column by the absolute value of the difference between the corresponding column and the weight. SORTN and the first 1 returns only the first value, meaning the closest to the weight

```
=MAP(K6:K,L6:L,LAMBDA(type,wt,IF(wt="","",SORTN(D4:D,1,,BYROW(INDEX(E4:H,,XMATCH(type,E3:H3)),LAMBDA(d,ABS(wt-d))),1))))
```

Let me know!

Comment: thanks - this is definitely impressive. I found one situation where it's not working the way i would have hoped - and perhaps i didn't explain properly. the value in M7 should be 14 not thirteen as 370 is closer to the neapolitan value for a 14inch than a 13 inch. any suggestions there?

Comment: to clarify - in the case of M8 - 370 for a neapolitan pizza is closer to a 14" than a 13" pie so i'd want the value returned to be 14 not 13.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try and deploy this on the real sheet now so you may here from me again when i mess up your fine work. cheers.

Comment: Good luck with that!

Comment: worked flawlessly. I was on that problem for days so i thank you for that. I have another question for you but I need to formulate exactly how to ask so don't be surprised if i reply in a day or so to this.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! I suggest you publish a new question with the new details, your progress and sample to work with ;)

Comment: Good suggestion. As this is more about tructuring data and less about the formula (since you gave me the working formula).

Comment: okay posted the other question. cheers

Comment: Martin: you are doing some very good answers to off-topic questions. However, unfortunately this may encourage the production of more off-topic questions. It would be ideal if you could answer only if the question is self-contained, i.e. worksheets and formulae are contained within the question. A link to a spreadsheet is OK, but not if the question relies upon it.