# Should I be trying to concatenate this data or is there a better way? & Help changing content from hard coded to dynamic

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqkXO8sdpeP9GPerdg8o2zcSiTV7o8gA-07iBvqw4Yw/edit#gid=1783566376

Attached is a workbook, currently the workbook functions just for Round Style pizzas only. Another user here created the formula used in Data!D1. What that formula is doing is taking the weight from column C, using the style from column b, and looking at the round table to find the closest match. for example - a 335 wt NY/Thin pizza displays as 15" because that's the closest size from the table on the round sheet.

What I would like to do is concatenate all of the styles so that colB on data includes everything from round and square & output the correct answer in C. I have a sneaking suspicion this is not an effective way to do this so please feel free to come at it from another direction.

One other thing:

On square - I have the following formulas in f1 and g1 respectively:

```
={"Detroit";ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D="","",$E2:$E*$D2:$D*$B2))}
={"Sicilian";ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D="","",$E2:$E*$D2:$D*$B3))}
```

The last value from B is hard coded - is there a way to dynamically generate that so when a new style is added to A & B is filled in - that the cells in row 1 don't have to be hard coded like that?

In the data sheet - I want people to be able to fill in any one of the round or square styles (I created named ranges), in the size sheet.

Comment: @martín here is the question in case you have any thoughts.

Comment: Hello again. I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Are you taking about Data tab? You want to collapse some columns in only one? If you're using that information later and will have to disaggregate again that concatenated info, probably isn't a good choice because you'll have unnecessary calculations. If I'm not getting the picture, please upload some example on how do you expect the final result to be

Comment: @Martín hey there - thanks and sorry - i was tired when i put up that post and left out the desired output for square pies in the data sheet. check the data tab now & see if that doesn't clarify. Your point about concatenation makes a lot of sense. I'm open to adding more fields as well if it helps in anyway.

Comment: Pro tip: on Stack Overflow we want questions to be "self-contained". That means that questions should be understandable without external links (and any links that are supplied are interesting but not necessary to understand the problem). I accept that spreadsheets are rather hard to replicate in a question, but nevertheless the rule stands. This is so that, once your spreadsheet is repaired, the question still contains a valid representation of the problem (the question makes no sense if the spreadsheet is fixed).

Comment: @halfer i certainly get that there needs to be a set of standards and quality controls on a place like this - however, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. What about my spreadsheet needs to be repaired?

Comment: @Martín i found a problem in some of my criteria. If you look at Data!C2&C5, those values are too small for anything in the charts. I tried wrapping an IF statment, but that made it worse. I am thinking that having an error message displaying "Too Small" would work great there but in trying to wrap your formula in an if statment - i kept breaking it. Any suggestions? Similarly, the values in C3&C6 are technically too big. So would there be a way to display a "Too Big" message? I would think that in both of those cases I'd have to set an upper and lower limit somewhere

Comment: You need to show the problem you are having, in the question itself (i.e. it needs to make sense without the link). See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Following the process of your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75479130/having-problems-converting-formulas-to-arrays-some-other-related-issues/75479395?noredirect=1#comment133175230_75479395), I added an IFERROR to did the same but with two columns joining with "X" in Square sheet. I understand your second expected value is not correct, but check it in my new column

```
={"Size";MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(type,wt,SI(wt="","", IFERROR (SORTN(Round!D2:D,1,,BYROW(INDEX(Round!E2:Z,,XMATCH(type,Round!E1:1)),LAMBDA(d,ABS(wt-d))),1),JOIN("x",SORTN(Square!D2:E,1,,BYROW(INDEX(Square!F2:Z,,XMATCH(type,Square!F1:1)),LAMBDA(d,ABS(wt-d))),1))))))}
```

About being the best way or not, it will be depending upon you need it for further calculations or not

Comment: This looks great. I am curious why the value in Data!F6 doesn't match my expected return but I'm exploring that.

Should I combine Round & Square into a single sheet?
If you take a look at Round! I have some notes about the values in ColA and the display in Row1? I was thinking i need to use indirect in order to automatically populate those cells. I want it to be dynamic so that it stays alphabetized.

Finally, if you are a fan of pizza, i'm more than happy to share with you the full version of the tool. you've been a great help.

Comment: ahh - your formula is working properly, my data was just bad.